# Drupal: PHP field for allowed values

Tags: php, drupal-6

I'm working in Drupal 6 with CCK. Under each text field there is a PHP section where you can run some PHP code to get allowed values. I'm running into trouble using an "if" statement to change the allowed values based on user type

So to start, I do a query to determine current users user type. -1 is default user, which is employees and user type id "1", is for site users. What I want is to restrict the site user to only the allowed values they need to see, while allowing employees to edit that value when on the node edit screen with all choices.

The first part of the if statement works. However, the "else" part doesn't work. Is this field set up to deal with control structures?

```
global $user;
$sql1 = "SELECT user_type_id FROM user_types_user WHERE uid = ".$user->uid." ";
$res1 = db_query($sql1);
if($res1 == '1'){
$sql = "SELECT account FROM users WHERE uid = ".$user->uid." ";
$res = db_query($sql);
while($row = db_fetch_array($res)){
$rows[] = $row['account'];
}
$rows = drupal_map_assoc($rows);
return $rows;
}
else {
$sql2 = "SELECT title FROM node WHERE type = 'accounts' ";
$res2 = db_query($sql2);
while($row2 = db_fetch_array($res2)){
$rows2[] = $row2['title'];
}
$rows2 = drupal_map_assoc($rows2);
return $rows2;
}
```

The choices are type=accounts in nodes, however, when a user is created one of the choices is selected and stored in the user table, under a column I created named "account"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'the "else part does not work' you mean that it is never executed, even if `user_type_id` does not equal 1, it might be the missing `db_fetch_array()` on `$res1`. You're comparing your result object directly to the string `'1'`, not the field value.

Comment: You are the man! Just so I'm straight, the problem was that the result of my array was an integer, but I was trying to compare it to a string? So, even thought they were the same, they weren't equal?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what happens, but PHP hat some weird rules for comparison when types don't match (see the docs at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Drupal's `db_query` seems to return a resource, which is converted to a number (probably 1). If adding `db_fetch_array` helps, great :-) I tripped over comparison problems more than once...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code for this. There may have been a quicker/shorter way to do this.

```
global $user;
$sql1 = "SELECT user_type_id FROM user_types_user WHERE uid = ".$user->uid." ";
$res1 = db_query($sql1);
while($type = db_fetch_array($res1)){
$types[] = $type['user_type_id'];
}
$resType = $types[0];
if($resType == "1"){
$sql = "SELECT account FROM users WHERE uid = ".$user->uid." ";
$res = db_query($sql);
while($row = db_fetch_array($res)){
$rows[] = $row['account'];
}
$rows = drupal_map_assoc($rows);
return $rows;
}
else {
$sql2 = "SELECT title FROM node WHERE type = 'accounts' ";
$res = db_query($sql2);
while($row2 = db_fetch_array($res)){
$rows2[] = $row2['title'];
}
return $rows2;
}
```